# RIA Services - Client side generated code not being re-generated with changes to Domain Service

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I am fairly new to Entity Framework and RIA Services, but I thought I had a reasonable grasp of it and was happily making changes to the entity model and adding subsequent changes to the Domain Service to provide availability to the client-side Silverlight application.

However, I made a change today to effectively introduce a many-to-many relationship on an entity, seemed reasonably straightforward. I then changed the Domain Service metadata to include the new EntityCollections that model the navigation properties etc.

This all seemed to go fine but when I tried to re-build the changes to the domain service they were not reflected in the client-side generated code.

I have tried absolutely everything, deleting the generated code, cleaning the whole solution and rebuilding, removing the RIA link and re-adding it, triple checking that the changes on the server side are correct (and they appear to be) and removing any code temporarily in the client that uses this entity so I can rebuild successfully.

I've pretty much run out of ideas as to why this code isn't being re-generated correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to RIA Services lack of support for Many-to-many relationships, just found this out.